# InfoPath 2010 form into Sharepoint Online - iPad

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, library

I'm trying to create some InfoPath forms in a SharePoint Online Document Library. I have created the forms in InfoPath Designer 2010 and published them to the Document Library. These forms have been enabled as a 'Web Browser Form' in the Form Options.

From a Desktop / Citrix Environment (Using IE11 / Chrome / Firefox) when pressing the 'New' Button It will open up the InfoPath form within the browser. I can Fill in the fields and save my form. This will then save the form to the relevant Library. I'm also able to view and open these forms.

When I log in to my SharePoint Online site using Safari / Chrome / IOS SharePoint App I get an error message when pressing the 'New' button when in the Document Library.

The error message I get is very generic and just says

> 'Sorry, Something Went Wrong' An unexpected error has occurred'.

This then gives me an ID and a look to troubleshoot issues with MS SharePoint Foundation.

When trying to view an existing form that has already been entered it seems to be working fine.

Has anybody got InfoPath forms working on iPad / Safari before? - How did you configure this?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working using Infopath 2013 instead of 2010. 2010 was compatible with sharepoint online through pc browser but struggled on iPad / Safari / ios App by the looks of it.